# How to get a given user's AppData directory in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, appdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the path of a Windows "special folder" for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198124/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-windows-special-folder-for-a-specific-user)

Is it possible to get the application data directory for a given user who is NOT the user running the program in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198124/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-windows-special-folder-for-a-specific-user

Comment: Given admin permissions, you should be able to find it. However, it really violates the spirit of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

One simple, slightly hacky way, is to get the %appdata% directory for the user who *is* running the program, then swap out their username with the username you are interested in.  It should work 99% of the time, but might fail on rare occasions.