# Path for getting the folder when program run as Service

Tags: visual-c++, service

I have an executable that is to be run as a Service in windows. Since the service runs as Local system, what should be the folder I should be writing any data the program uses. As currently, I use %LocalAppData% but when the exe runs as Service it points me to

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData
```

I used following code:

```
std::string GetLocalAppDataPath()
{
    HANDLE hfile;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,NULL,0, szPath))) 
    {
        std::string path = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(szPath);
        boost::replace_all(path, "\\", "\\\\");
        return path;
    }
}
```

If I call the above code as:

```
std::string app_data_path = GetLocalAppDataPath();
std::string log_folder_path = app_data_path + "\\\\lpa\\\\output\\\\";
```

I get **C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\lpa\output\** instead of my own Local App Data Folder. So Should I be using other folder that LocalSystem can access.?

Answer (score 1):

did you try this:
[Get CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA path for any user on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131716/get-csidl-local-appdata-path-for-any-user-on-windows)

Comment: I am using C++ for exe